# Video gets choppy and stuck in full screen mode when streaming videos

Tags: nvidia, video, streaming

Have an interesting problem on my hands. When streaming videos in full-screen on netflix in either chromium or firefox, after a while (about 20-30 minutes in) the video will get choppy every 2 minutes or so. I also cannot exit full screen video mode using any of the standard techniques (Esc, f11, alt+tab, alt+esc, Ctl+Alt+Del short or long press). I literally have to hard boot to escape the scenario. Any help is great! I'm rusty but can run any queries from the terminal you think I should pull.

I currently run a dual boot windows 10/Ubuntu 18.04.6 64-bit on a Lenovo y700.
Other specs:
Gnome 3.28.2
8 gig ram
Intel i7-6700HQ 2.6 ghz X8 processor
GeForce GTX 960M graphics card (GM107M), currently set to use NVIDIA driver metapackage from nvidia-driver-460(proprietary). Driver Version 460.91.03
Can provide additional stats from Nvidia X Server Menu if needed.

Thanks anyone!!

Comment: did you install codecs? `sudo apt-get install ubuntu-restricted-extras` Please [edit] your question accordingly.